# How to clear/reset all CoreData in one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, ios6, persistent-storage

I am using coreData, with one -to-many realtionship, I have a folder entity and a file entity. A folder can have many files and so on.

So, I have two ViewControllers, FolderViewController and FileViewController which contains folders and files respectively.Now I have a modalView , which is accesible from both folder and file viewcontroller. In this VC I have a button to Reset all Data. So when I click this I want all the data should reset.

I used this code,this function is written in appdelegate.m and called from my VC.

```
- (void)resetToDefault
{
    NSError * error;
    // retrieve the store URL
    NSURL * storeURL = [[__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] URLForPersistentStore:[[[__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject]];
    // lock the current context
    [__managedObjectContext lock];
    [__managedObjectContext reset];//to drop pending changes
    //delete the store from the current managedObjectContext
    if ([[__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:[[[__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject] error:&error])
    {
        // remove the file containing the data
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
        //recreate the store like in the  appDelegate method
        [[__managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];//recreates the persistent store
    }
    [__managedObjectContext unlock];
    //that's it !

    NSLog(@"buttonReset Pressed");
}
```

So after clicking on resetButton when I close the View, I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'
```

So how to solve this.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: what you are trying to do? remove __every__ thing in CoreData?

Comment: I mean I want to remove all folders and all files inside each folder  and the app should be in its default state.

Comment: you mean make the app like just installed?

Comment: @xlc0212, do you know how to solve this

Comment: sorry don't have a clear solution at moment

Comment: @xlc0212, but did you get what I meant

Comment: yea I think I understand your question. anyway, you may need to search how to switch persistentStoreCoordinator

Comment: I think the problem is with NSFetchResultsController

Comment: More details needed to understand your issue. Like which line raise the exception (see exceptions breakpoints). Also how do you retrieve your NSManagedObjectContext in this code. Giving a look / using https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord could also help.

Comment: Hi @VincentG, I solved this please have a look at my answer below and let me know whether I am right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete/Reset all entries in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077810/delete-reset-all-entries-in-core-data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved this problem, below is the code,

This function has been written in appdelegate.m

```
- (void) resetApplicationModel
{
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppName.sqlite"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
    for (NSManagedObject *ct in [self.managedObjectContext registeredObjects]) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:ct];
    }

    //Make new persistent store for future saves   
    if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // do something with the error
    }  
}
```

And in my SettingsViewController, I am calling this on resetbutton clicked in this way.

```
- (void)resetButtonclicked
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate resetApplicationModel];  
}
```

Regards
Ranjit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSPersistentStore *store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores lastObject];
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    [storeCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];
//    Then, just add the persistent store back to ensure it is recreated properly.    
    if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

Comment: You have a "CoreDataManager" ?

Comment: For manage your Core Data (create, delete...) like this https://gist.github.com/3967514 (without delete this)