# Clearing Core Data

Tags: core-data

I am in search of an easy way to clear all data logged into core data model. Please note that I don't want this to happen every time the app is opened. I merely need an easy way to clear test data that has been recorded from a text input. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing CoreData and all that inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727583/clearing-coredata-and-all-that-inside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the installed app from the device. This gets rid of all coredata entries and other saved entries.

There is also a programmatic solution mentioned here [Clearing CoreData and all that inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727583/clearing-coredata-and-all-that-inside)

Comment: Thanks a ton! A quick and easy solution. Perfect!